# Is it possible for absolute paths to autocomplete in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)?

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code

When writing a javascript app, it's possible to create an `.env` file in the root directory containing just e.g:

```
NODE_PATH=src/
```

Which sets up allowing for absolute paths e.g: in import statements in code.

e.g: I can be working on the file `/src/actions/index.js` and enter:

```
import { SAVE_COMMENT } from "actions/types";
```

..and the import works, but there is no auto-complete and I wonder:  Is it possible to auto-complete after I type just:

```
import { SAVE_COMMENT } from "actions/
```

?

Relative-path lookup continues to work great. In fact, the relative path lookup is one of my favorite features of vs-code and one of the reasons I use it, so it would be very nice for it to work when absolute paths are configured, too.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

VS Code does not support using `NODE_PATH` for intellisense. To achieve what you want, create a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson) file at the root of your project with the contents:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "baseUrl": "./src"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

The important setting is `baseUrl`. It tells VS Code to resolve non-relative paths relative to the `./src` folder

After configuring `jsconfig` and `baseUrl`, you can also set `"javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative"` in VS Code to specify that VS Code should always try to use paths to use the `baseUrl`

Comment: This works, and if your root directory isn't `./src` then `./` is fine as in my case.

Comment: If you're using a CI/CD, abs paths can be a source of problems, don't forget to update your config there as well.

Comment: This does not seem to work with real absolute URLs starting with `/` as [the EcmaScript standard allows and e.g. browsers implement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_a_single_export_from_a_module). So it works for `from "src/actions/index.js"`, but not for `from "/src/actions/index.js"`.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://lmichelin.fr/vscode-intellisense-jsconfig-vue-js-nuxt-js-absolute-imports/) is a nice guide for **Vue.js** and **Nuxt.js** projects configuration in VS Code

Answer (score -1):

this is the solution that worked for me

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "core/*": ["./src/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

I am using webpack and absolute paths